# Sliding window of 10 seconds?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

You are given an infinite stream of words (no spaces), each word also has an attached timestamp, starting at `0` and its in the format like `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 6`. We have APIs:

```
public class StreamClass {

  public void consumeNextString(String next, int timeStamp);
  public String getStrings(); // joins all strings into space seprated string using the below constraint

}
```

You are to implement both these functions. `getStrings`, specifically has the behavior that if you say had a stream like

```
one : 4
the: 5
hello : 12
the : 14
menlo: 15
```

If you got called `getStrings` now, it should print `one hello the menlo` instead of `one the hello the menlo` since `the` is duplicated at timestamp `11, 14` (current timestamp is `15`). The oldest `the` at timestamp 5 got disregarded.

Later on, after the stream looks like:

```
one : 4
the: 5
hello : 12
the : 14
menlo: 15
big: 123
```

`getStrings` should print `one the hello the menlo big` because there are no duplicates in the last 10 second window (current timestamp is 123)

**Work:** I am thinking of an optimal way to do this, this is from an interview question.
The problem is, I dont see any good way of doing this other than just brute force, ie, storing every string then manually looking at the 10 second window to take out the oldest string, but surely there must be SOMETHING more optimal?

Comment: It is a good problem. But, imo, interview questions are not supposed to be made public. It allows other test takers to copy/paste the solution if they encounter the same problem. You should work this out yourself, with some friends/colleagues rather than having someone posting a solution online.

Comment: I'd recommend you to delete this, and make a new post without identifiable information but with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Make an honest attempt at solving this, if you are stuck somewhere, we can help you out.

Comment: Take a look at the java.util.Map interface and what it can do.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: @ysmflsd for the second example, we should print only 1 - 'the' right as the first 'the' happens at 5 and the next one happens at 14. so it's within the 10 sec window.

Comment: You can implement this with source storage (list of custom object or pair) and tracking storage like map find the duplicate and a queue for duplicate values (as per time stamp) when getString is called. another way instead of queue, you can have map of int,list to process each entry as it comes in, where each list will have elements for corresponding timestap(key) as per duplicate timeframe.

Comment: There is no optimal way. It depends on what you want to optimize. Do you want `consumeNextString` to be as fast as possible? Do you want `getStrings` to be as fast as possible? Do you want to use as little memory as possible? ...

Comment: @zenwraight I think the question is only about the last 10 second window. In the second example only duplicates between 113 and 123 should be printed only one time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a possible solution.

- I used two Lists to hold the  `words` and their `timestamps`.
- The field `lastTimeStamp` is updated as each entry is consumed.  It is used
  to maintain the local window of seconds
- when the last windows of time is entered, I simply iterate over the list of words removing the oldest duplicates.
- after `getString()` is called, all lists are cleared to start the process anew.

This works for the supplied data and other data I have tested.

```
public class SlidingWindow10seconds {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamClass sc = new StreamClass();
        sc.consumeNextString("one", 4);
        sc.consumeNextString("the", 5);
        sc.consumeNextString("hello", 12);
        sc.consumeNextString("the", 14);
        sc.consumeNextString("menlo", 15);
        System.out.println(sc.getStrings());
        sc.consumeNextString("one", 4);
        sc.consumeNextString("the", 5);
        sc.consumeNextString("hello", 12);
        sc.consumeNextString("the", 14);
        sc.consumeNextString("menlo", 15);
        sc.consumeNextString("big", 123);
        System.out.println(sc.getStrings());    
    }
```

Prints

```
one the hello menlo
one the hello the menlo big
```

```
class StreamClass {
    int lastTimeStamp = 0;
    final int windowSize = 10;
    List<Integer> timeStamps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public void consumeNextString(String next, int timeStamp) {
        words.add(next);
        timeStamps.add(timeStamp);
        lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getStrings() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            int ts = timeStamps.get(i);
            // append all words if outside the window
            if (ts < lastTimeStamp - windowSize) {
                sb.append(words.get(i) + " ");
            } else {
                // Now iterate thru the list removing the oldest
                // duplicates by adding in reverse order
                Set<String> distinct = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                for (int k = words.size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
                    distinct.add(words.get(k));
                }
                // and now reverse that using stack.
                Stack<String> stk = new Stack<>();
                stk.addAll(distinct);

                while(!stk.isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(stk.pop()+" ");
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length()-1);
        words.clear();
        timeStamps.clear();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```